# Repairing corrupted GeoPackage

Tags: qgis, geopackage, corrupt

QGIS doesn't recognize a GeoPackage ("*invalid source*"), DB Manager connects to the *.gpkg* but doesn't find the file ("*file not found*") when trying to open.

The software DB Browser for SQLite said:

> Can't open the database file. Database disk image is malformed.

The project QGIS was closed regularly after saving everything.

How do I repair the corrupted *.gpkg*?

Comment: Maybe this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18259692/how-to-recover-a-corrupt-sqlite3-database. Possible reasons for corruption https://www.sqlite.org/howtocorrupt.html

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Answer (score 1):

A geopackage file (.gpkg) is stored as a SQLite3 database. What I found is that when you read/copy a geopackage when it's already in use (for example by connecting to it in QGIS) the database will be locked (read-only).

You'll experience the `Can't open the database file. Database disk image is malformed` error whenever you try to open a locked gpkg file.

In my case, the solution was to make sure the .gpkg wasn't in use anywhere else before reading/copying.

If you need to unlock a gpkg (sqlite3 database) - check out this SO thread: https://stackoverflow.com/q/151026/2550702